# hasNext(pattern) не срабатывает на корректную строку после ввода некорректной

Tags: java

```
private static void test1() {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String pattern = "^([0-9]{1,2})$";
    while (!s.hasNext(pattern)) {
        System.out.println("Not match");
        s.next();
    }
    System.out.println("match");
}
```

При вводе строки `11` в консоль выводится "match" и происходит выход из метода. Если ввести в консоль неподходящую строку для паттерна, например: `aaa` в консоль выводится "Not match". Но если после неподходящей строки ввести подходящую `11`, то все равно выводится "Not match". В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Мне кажется дело в регулярном выражении, а именно в том, что совпадение должно быть от начала до конца строки. Сверьте вывод  с тем что ожидаете увидеть на http://regexr.com/

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov в этом случае и первичный правильный ввод считался бы не корректным. Или вы имеете ввиду, что какой-нибудь остаток первого ввода попадает во второй? Вроде возврата карретки? Думал об этом, но я преобразовывал полученную из сканера строку через toCharArray и сравнивал количества символов. И при первичном корректном, и при вторичном корректном после некорректного количество символов содержало ровно то, что ввел, никаких служебных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Scanner`  имеет внутреннее состояние, буфер в который записывается ввод. Полученные строки делятся на лексемы, согласно разделителю, который можно задать методом `useDelimiter(pattern)`.

Смотрим, что делает метод `hasNext`

> Returns true if the next token matches the pattern constructed from the specified string. The scanner does not advance past any input.

Т.е. имеем, такую ситуацию при которой во внутренний буфер накапливается ввод. По этому вводу ищется совпадение. Регулярному выражению `^([0-9]{1,2})$` содержимое буфера не удовлетворяет, т.к. ему должна соответствовать вся строка целиком. Чтобы исправить это, уберите ограничение на начало и конец строки.